# Pushing single changeset in Mercurial when multiple are available

Tags: mercurial

I have 5 outgoing changesets available to push from my local Mercurial repo, and I only want to push one of these at this time. This one changeset lies in the middle of all available.

For example I have the following revisions:

- 6639
- 6546
- 6545
- 6544
- 6543

and I only want to push 6545. Any easy way to do this?

Comment: would using branches be more effective? Usually when I have separate functionality I put it in different branches. You can always pull in changes from one branch to another if you need them, but that way non-related code in your 3rd branch (5645) is separate from all other code and easily accessible by itself

Comment: normally yes, I use branches for this sort of thing. I happen to need to make a change to a build config file that happens to be in the same repo that I've made code changes in. Bleh!

Comment: It depends on the parent of that changeset. I assume 6544 is the parent of r6545?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not possible. A revision must put a repository in a definite state, but if you could push 6545 and the remote repository updated to it, it would not include the changes from earlier (not pushed) revsets. This goes against the core design of mercurial. What you can do is:

a) distribute a diff (patch) that contains the same changes as rev 6545. You can do this via `hg diff` or in other ways, but applying the patch is not inherently connected to your rev 6545: it is a separate revision that "happens" to make the same changes. If you're lucky, they can be merged in the future without problems. Or

b) rewrite your history, temporarily (with the mq extension) or permanently (with the help `rebase` or other extensions) so that 6545 is placed immediately after the already-commited revisions. You can then push it like any other revision whose ancestors have already been pushed.

Answer (score 17):

You can only push the consecutive list of changesets up to the required.

So

```
hg push -r 6545
```

will push `6543..6545`.

And you cannot push just `6545` because without preceding changesets its changes make no sense.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Mercurial Queues](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/MqExtension) extension to do this.  You may need to enable the mq extension which is detailed on the linked page.

You would import all the revisions into the queue, pop them all off the stack and then apply the one that you want before pushing and then applying the rest.  Something like this:

```
> hg qimport --rev 6639
> hg qimport --rev 6543:6546
> hg qpop --all
> hg qpush --move 6545.diff

Here you might have to resolve conflicts

> hg qfinish --applied
> hg push
> hg qpush --all

Again, might need to resolve conflicts here.
```

This has left your repository with revision `6545` applied and pushed (but with a different revision number now) and the rest of your changes applied and not pushed.